# How can I load data from a service that returns JSON and create content using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am a beginner in JS .. so I am reaching out to you, hoping someone could enlighten me! :)

I have been given a JSON link listing a lot of infos and I must create an html using at least 2 pieces of info from this JSON link.

I have already imported my stylesheets (+script) in the html and I coded this in my script.js :

```
$.getJSON('myjsonlink', function(json) {
  console.log(json);
});
```

If one of you guys have a moment to give me hand, it would be awesome! Thank you so much in advance.
Athena.

Comment: Have you tried any thing to read from JSON response and updated HTML content based on that?

Comment: Can you share how would you like to display the data, coming from the api or json link? Like the structure

Comment: @Athena if i understood the question very well you wanna get data from a JSON file and update or add content to your html (web page) with that data

Comment: @Rilla yes exactly! but when I try to code that based on what I understood from my course, nothing shows up..

Comment: @NikhilSingh I would like to do something really simple (then style it with css). I have to present the universe of the anime Naruto so, basically, it would be a header H1, maybe an interactive button to load the data and then just the images, titles and synopsis of the animes (which are listed in the json link). I don't know if I am very clear.. I hope so

Comment: @DipenShah yes I did try. But I feel like I am missing an important part of the process since it does not work as expected..

Comment: @Athena would you be able to share piece of returned JSON and code you used so that someone can assist you better?

Comment: It would be great if you could share some sample json object, kind of you are getting right now. Then its just about writing some HTML with some JS variable inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with the way you are reading data and rendering it:

1. There is no `naruto` property on response, it is `results` instead.
2. `img` is not a valid property, it should be `image_url` instead.

Let's fix it:

```js
$('#get-data').click(function() {
  var showData = $('#show-data');
  $.getJSON('https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime?q=naruto', function(data) {
    var naruto = data.results;
    for (var i = 0; i < naruto.length; i++) {
      var anime = naruto[i];
      var html = '<div class="card">' + '<img src="' + anime.image_url + '">' + '<div class="cardcontainer">' + '<p>' + anime.title + '</p>' + '<p>' + anime.synopsis + '</p>' + '</div>' + '</div>';
      showData.append(html);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="get-data">Load Data</button>
<div id="show-data"></div>
```

Comment: should i use a <div class="card"> or "cardcontainer" to show the json data...? I don't know

Comment: I think I have an issue with how to concretely create my "div class card" to load and finally show my data...

Comment: @Athena if you copy and paste exact code, it should just work. I am not sure what do you mean by using `card` or `cardcontainer`, it depends on your stylesheet and CSS classes there are no fixed/predefined classes.

Comment: I did copy paste the code but nothing happens when I click on the button 'load data' on my webpage. What am I supposed to do to show the data of the json link?

Comment: Could you share your code in jsfiddle? If you run code snippet on stackoverflow it is loading and working as expected!

Comment: @Athena I asked you to copy and paste code as it is in here. 1. please don't share code in comments, either share it in jsfiddle or pastebin. 2. You are calling wrong endpoint to get data, update it to `$.getJSON('https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime?q=naruto')` and it will work.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still learning how to use stack overflow.. could you please explain to me how to use jsfiddle or pastebin. I don't understand how and I would like to show you my final code. Thank you so much for you help

Comment: @Athena no worries, `jsfiddler` is a site which allows you to create code snippet and share. For example I created: https://jsfiddle.net/zgw2c1br/, you can update it with your code, save it and share the url with me. Pastebin is also an online tool which allows your to copy something, generate a link and share it with others.

Comment: I just tried my code on jsfiddler and you are right, it works!!! but I do the same thing on Glitch.com (the platform on which I must create and submit my work), the 'load data' button does not work. Same for repl.it. Do you have any idea why?